# LogStash date filter error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I've just upgraded from 5.2 to 5.6 in my test environment.

After the upgrade my logstash filter for date stopped working.

I'm getting a date of `"Sep 26 11:01:41"` and matching on

`"match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  dd HH:mm:ss" ]"`

it throws

`JSON parse error, original data now in message field {:error=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unrecognized token 'Sep': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many spaces in your pattern `"MMM  dd HH:mm:ss"` should be `"MMM dd HH:mm:ss"`

```
"match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]"
                                    ^
                                    |
                                   here
```

Comment: [2017-09-26T12:32:18,081][ERROR][logstash.codecs.json     ] JSON parse error, original data now in message field {:error=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unrecognized token 'Sep': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: Sep 26 12:32:13 sh01 sshd[22959]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.30 port 52808 [preauth]; line: 1, column: 4]>, :data=>"Sep 26 12:32:13 hostname1 sshd[22959]: Connection closed by 10.x.x.x port 52808 [preauth]"}

Comment: You probably need to show more of your config and a sample log line.

Comment: [GIST with log and config](https://gist.github.com/samimb/95e76495600b6e66bf17050fd942e8c1)

Comment: Can you share a sample log line that you're willing to parse?

Comment: Ok got it `Sep 26 15:25:51 hostname1 sshd[21163]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.30 port 50994 [preauth]; line: 1, column: 4`

Comment: What kind of codec are you using in your input? json or plain?

Comment: Sample added to Gist.

Comment: Can you add your input config to the gist, too?

Comment: Can you comment out all filters and add this output: `output{stdout{codec=>rubydebug}}`. Then paste one event you get to the gist, please.

Comment: For some reason they are tagged as type log and not syslog

Comment: You must have a `type: log` somewhere in your beats configuration. Can you check?

Comment: Figured out what is wrong.. :(.. I haven't played with this enovironment for quite a while which is not good for my memory :). beats input is not meant to be used for syslog. I have a syslog input for that. the beats one is for an IDS. I.e beats parsing is set to only handle my IDS input and not syslog.

Comment: Indeed, glad you figured out

Answer (score 0):

I have found an issue on your log

```
  input {
     beats {
        port => 5044
       ssl => true
       ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
       ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
       codec => json
      }
}
```

try remove the

`codec => json`

seems the input data is not json format ,just remove it and try